# Custom function to return certain values

Tags: functions

I built up the following formula to return *a*, *b*, *c* and *d* exponential functions if *k* is a positive intiger from *1* to *4*;
4=a,
3=b,
2=c,
1=d,

(a×**((k-3)×(k-2)×(k-1))**×*(1/6)*)+
(b×**((k-4)×(k-2)×(k-1))**×*(-1/2)*)+
(c×**((k-4)×(k-3)×(k-1))**×*(1/2)*)+
(d×**((k-4)×(k-3)×(k-2))**×*(-1/6)*)

I came up with the solution where the bold expressions are intented to eleminate the other possible values of *k* and italic fractions are correction to return *1* in order to return relevant *a*, *b*, *c* or *d* value. I can build up more consecutive patterns for but it becomes longer when I add more values.

Is there any shorter method to achieve this?

Comment: why the fractions?

Comment: I dont know what is fractions unfotunately. I am not good with maths. Thats why I came up with a clumsy solution.

Comment: Like why the 1/2, -1/6, etc

Comment: Ah, I call them corrections. They flatten the whole statement as 1 in order to return a, b, c or d if the correct k value is given.

Comment: Sorry, what is this this function intended to do?

Comment: @Litestone You should state this in the question! Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: @AlexVong Ok. It was in the question but I made it more specific

Comment: @Litestone Also, is your function correct? If we put $k = 1$, then we get $d$ but not $a$.

Comment: @AlexVong Arrghh just reversve order. Fixed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Litestone Are we allowed to use piecewise-defined function? So e.g. $$\begin{cases} a \text{ if } k = 1 \\ b \text{ if } k = 2 \\ c \text{ if } k = 3 \\ d \text{ if } k = 4 \\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: @AlexVong I don't know what it is but everything is allowed as long as I can express in Excel and makes my work easier if I want add extra values values like: *8=a*, *7=b*, *6=c*, *5=d*, *4=e*, *3=f*, *2=g*, *1=h* It is not about the calculation itself actually. I am after a shorter method serves as the intented purpose.

Comment: If you are using Excel, you can easily write a macro to look up the value  of "a" given "k".

Comment: @NoChance Yes but the deal is I want to expres this with a function.

Comment: Mathematically, you could use Lagrange polynomial, but I am not sure if it is easier or not. If you get new points you will have to change the equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

$$\begin{align}
a (1 - |\operatorname{sgn}(k - 1)|) \\
+ b (1 - |\operatorname{sgn}(k - 2)|) \\
+ c (1 - |\operatorname{sgn}(k - 3)|) \\
+ d (1 - |\operatorname{sgn}(k - 4)|)
\end{align}$$
where $\operatorname{sgn}$ denotes the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

## Long version

Your formula is a good starting point. However, its length grows quadratically (i.e. $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$) with the number of variables ($a, b, c, d, \dots$) which is bad.

I come up with the above formula by first defining the following function:
$$s(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if } x = 0 \\
0 \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

Observe that the formula you wanted can then be written as:
$$\begin{align}
a \cdot s(k - 1) \\
+ b \cdot s(k - 2) \\
+ c \cdot s(k - 3) \\
+ d \cdot s(k - 4)
\end{align}$$
Now it remains to find a formula for $s(x)$ using functions available in spreadsheet. Well, it is not hard to see that:
$$|\operatorname{sgn}(x)| =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } x = 0 \\
1 \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

So we have $$s(x) = 1 - |\operatorname{sgn}(x)|$$

Putting all the above into one big formula gives us the formula in the beginning. Note that its length grows linearly (i.e. $\mathcal{O}(n)$) with the number of variables ($a, b, c, d, \dots$) which is better than quadratic and is the best we can hope for.

Comment: Ok then I will accept this as answer since this is the only way to do

Comment: @Litestone Do you know how write the formula in spreadsheet?

Comment: surprisingly I am quite good with excel

Comment: @Litestone Okay!